# OTel Collector Contrib running in Azure Container App and not receiving any data

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, open-telemetry-collector

I used the following two articles to create an OTel Collector in an Azure Container App. The second article follows on from the first and fixed the issue with it starting correctly.

[Honeycomb blog on how to create an OTel Collector in an Azure App Container](https://www.honeycomb.io/blog/opentelemetry-collector-azure-container-apps)

[Adding an argument to point to your mounted config file on start up](https://blog.depechie.com/posts/2022-10-13-opentelemetry-on-azure-container-apps/)

I started with the Honeycomb article to build a collector in an Azure Container App and it wasn't starting correctly until the second blog post and added the 'args' section to point to my mounted config file. The collector is running and listening for otlp http traffic on port 4318 with the ingress set to allow external traffic. However, I cannot get it to receive any data from my .Net Core 7 api. I can get it all working on my laptop with the otel collector contrib running in docker desktop set to receive http traffic on port 4318.

Here is the config file for the container:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:

exporters:
  otlphttp/withauth:
    auth:
      authenticator: oauth2client
    logs_endpoint: $CNAO_LOGS_ENDPOINT
    metrics_endpoint: $CNAO_METRICS_ENDPOINT
    traces_endpoint: $CNAO_TRACES_ENDPOINT

  logging:
    loglevel: debug

processors:
  batch:
    send_batch_size: 8192
    timeout: 10s
  attributes/collector_info:
    actions:
      - key: collector.hostname
        value: $HOSTNAME
        action: insert
      - key: azure.container_app.revision
        value: $CONTAINER_APP_REVISION
        action: insert
      - key: azure.container_app.name
        value: $CONTAINER_APP_NAME
        action: insert
      - key: source.blog
        value: "true"
        action: insert
  filter/healthcheck:
    spans:
      exclude:
        match_type: strict
        attributes:
          - Key: http.target
            Value: /health

extensions:
  oauth2client:
    client_id: $CNAO_CLIENT_ID
    client_secret: $CNAO_CLIENT_SECRET
    token_url: $CNAO_TOKEN_URL

service:
  extensions: [oauth2client]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch,filter/healthcheck,attributes/collector_info]
      exporters: [logging, otlphttp/withauth]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlphttp/withauth]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlphttp/withauth]
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: "debug"
```

The log stream on the container shows that it has started successfully giving this output:

```
2023-10-16T10:41:15.15488  Connecting to the container 'collector'...

2023-10-16T10:41:15.17288  Successfully Connected to container: 'collector' [Revision: 'collector--1', Replica: 'collector--1']
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605516952Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:92 Processor is starting...    {"kind": "processor", "name": "batch", "pipeline": "logs"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605528072Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:96 Processor started.  {"kind": "processor", "name": "batch", "pipeline": "logs"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605566835Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:92 Processor is starting...    {"kind": "processor", "name": "attributes/collector_info", "pipeline": "traces"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605573347Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:96 Processor started.  {"kind": "processor", "name": "attributes/collector_info", "pipeline": "traces"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605622865Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:92 Processor is starting...    {"kind": "processor", "name": "filter/healthcheck", "pipeline": "traces"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605652090Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:96 Processor started.  {"kind": "processor", "name": "filter/healthcheck", "pipeline": "traces"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605657580Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:92 Processor is starting...    {"kind": "processor", "name": "batch", "pipeline": "traces"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605698870Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:96 Processor started.  {"kind": "processor", "name": "batch", "pipeline": "traces"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605707717Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:92 Processor is starting...    {"kind": "processor", "name": "batch", "pipeline": "metrics"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605711765Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:96 Processor started.  {"kind": "processor", "name": "batch", "pipeline": "metrics"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605715602Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:100    Starting receivers...
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605736781Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:104    Receiver is starting... {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "pipeline": "metrics"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605758522Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z warn    internal/warning.go:51  Using the 0.0.0.0 address exposes this server to every network interface, which may facilitate Denial of Service attacks    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "pipeline": "metrics", "documentation": "https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/security-best-practices.md#safeguards-against-denial-of-service-attacks"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605821510Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    otlpreceiver@v0.67.0/otlp.go:90 Starting HTTP server    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "pipeline": "metrics", "endpoint": "0.0.0.0:4318"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605855915Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:108    Receiver started.   {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "pipeline": "metrics"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605861705Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:104    Receiver is starting... {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "pipeline": "logs"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605888225Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:108    Receiver started.   {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "pipeline": "logs"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605897011Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:104    Receiver is starting... {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "pipeline": "traces"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605920645Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/pipelines.go:108    Receiver started.   {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "pipeline": "traces"}
2023-10-13T15:37:36.605927208Z 2023-10-13T15:37:36.605Z info    service/service.go:105  Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data.
```

The code I am using for the otlp exporter in my .Net Core 7 project to hit the container app is as follows:

```
string endPoint = "https://collector.onazure.azurecontainerapps.io:4318/v1/traces";
                            Console.WriteLine($"AppD Endpoint: {endPoint}");
                            builder.AddOtlpExporter(options =>
                            {
                                AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);

                                options.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.HttpProtobuf;
                                options.ExportProcessorType = ExportProcessorType.Batch;
                                options.Endpoint = new Uri(endPoint);
                            })
                            .AddConsoleExporter(options => options.Targets = ConsoleExporterOutputTargets.Console);
```

I have tried running the project locally on my laptop and also have the api in it's own container with an APIM in place to test the endpoints. I can see in the console logs that the Writeline is output when starting up the container and that telemetry is being sent to the Console through the Console Exporter. However, it is not being received by the collector.

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I sorted the issue. Answered below.

Comment: consider posting your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted the issue. At present Azure Container Apps only open one port, so you cannot map multiple ports like you can with Docker. Port 80 and 443 are open by default and I thought 4318 had successfully been opened as it says it's available in the Container overview. I used Telnet to confirm which ports were open and found 4318 was not available, so I tried sending the data to port 443 and it worked. My new endpoint is:

```
https://collector.onazure.azurecontainerapps.io:433/v1/traces
```